# 'Very nomagic' doesn't work as expected

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

`:h \V` tells me:

> Use of "\V" means that in the pattern after it only the backslash and the
>   terminating character (/ or ?) has a special meaning.  "very nomagic"

However:

```
:echo ')' =~# '\V\[)]}>\]'
```

Will tell me 0. How come so?

Comment: It's because your pattern expects a match for `')}>]'`.  This will match: `:echo ')' =~# '\V\[)]'`

Comment: But the special meaning of `[` and `]` would imply that it matches any of the enclosed characters; `:echo 'a' =~# '\v[abc]'` would match

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is now.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you misplaced a slash.  This is what it should look like:

```
:echo ')' =~# '\V\[)\]}>]'
```

`\[]` is a character collection with `nomagic` enabled.  Note that it doesn't close with `\]`.  Including an opening brace inside of the collection needs to be escaped with a slash.